# How to fix error when value in SQL contains an apostrophe

Tags: sql, firebird

I am updating a string in a table using a Firebird SQL statement, with information typed by a user. However, if the string entered by a user has an apostrophe then it creates an error because the SQL syntax no longer reads correctly.

I guess I could read the string and remove all instances of apostrophes, but I wonder if there is an easier way.

{Edit 17 May 2017}
I am using Firebird 2.5 (as part of a software program called Ostendo)

Here is an extract of the code:

```
 UpdatedMsg := frmPOLineNotesMemo.Lines.text;
 SQLUpdateStr := 'update ASSEMBLYLINES set LINENOTES = LINENOTES || '''+ UpdatedMsg +''' Where SYSUNIQUEID = ' + AssyPropertyLine + '';
 ExecuteSQL(SQLUpdateStr);
```

frmPOLineNotesMemo.Lines.Text is information entered by the user via a form.

Comment: Please show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this problem given some input, and please also list the version of Firebird.  Generally you don't want to remove the "odd" characters from user input if possible — "King's Cross" needs its apostrophe, after all — but you _do_ want to safely encode them.  There are several ways to do that depending on your interface or bindings to Firebird.

Comment: Use parameterized SQL - this is the correct and easy way.

Comment: You should really show your code. From your description, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should **never** concatenate values into a query string, and **always** use parameters. Parameters remove the SQL injection risk.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Just FYI, if a user is able to set UpdatedMsg to any string, then your code is susceptible to an injection attack (look it up).

Comment: I assume I don't need to use parameters when reading (E.g Select...), but definitely when writing (E.g. INSERT....). Or do I also need to use it for reading as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the apostrophes in the string.
Found here: https://firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg10-firebird-sql.html

However keep in mind the comments. User input should be passed as parameters to avoid security problems.